# Codedigniter dynamic uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lots of google search lots or research still unable to understand how do i create a uri in codigniter like i tried to create a dynamic link for my ads and listings for this i created a link in my view page like this

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(). "listings/".$subcat->cat_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcat->cat_name ; ?></a></li>
```

and on the second page i want to call the listings by id i could have done by using simple get method but it will show the link as listings?cat=&subcat= and so on but I don't want this i want it to be like uri segment

to call the above statement i did this but it says 404 not found as the there is no named page as cat_name which would be the category name

```
$cat = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
if ($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE)
{
    echo $cat = 0;
}
else
{
    echo $cat = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

and this is my controller listings.php

```
class listings extends CI_Controller {
     public function index() {
        $cat          = "mylist";
        $data['list'] = $cat;
        $this->load->view('listings', $data);
    }
}
```

Please can anyone help me out brothers

Comment: Do you have any other function than index function on listings controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add _remap to the controller.

```
public function _remap($method,$params = array()) {
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->$method($params);
    } else {
        $this->index($method, $params);
    }
}
```

This declare any parameters after "listings/" as parameters for index function if the first parameters is not equal to a function name in your class.

Then you can have access to parameters in your index function like this.

```
public function index($category = null, $params = null){

    $subcategory = $params[0];

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but if there is $cat and subcat i just have to pas the paramere and $1/$2 to the route and it will not effect the link right and i can call it by using this->uri->segment am i correct as link is placed in a different file ?

Comment: You're welcome. You're right I didn't quite catch you at first. I edited my answer I hope this can help.